# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, apache-stanbol

**I am trying to install stanbol and getting the following error**

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test
```

Attaching the error log

```
[INFO] 

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project org.apache.stanbol.entityhub.ldpath: There are test failures. [ERROR]  [ERROR] Please refer to /home/stanbol-trunk/entityhub/ldpath/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.

[ERROR] -> [Help 1] org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project org.apache.stanbol.entityhub.ldpath: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/stanbol-trunk/entityhub/ldpath/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.   at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)  at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)  at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)   at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)  at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)  at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356) Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/stanbol-trunk/entityhub/ldpath/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.   at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:82)  at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:254)   at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:854)    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:722)     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)  ... 19 more

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

[ERROR] 

[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :org.apache.stanbol.entityhub.ldpath
```

Answer (score 15):

It looks like you have some tests broken in the lib you are using.

Look at /home/stanbol-trunk/entityhub/ldpath/target/surefire-reports if you want details of the test errors.

If you want to install the lib anyway you can run `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ohhhh Working for me. Thanks for this post.

Comment: -DskipTests  Will it skip the test? if yes. i hope this will not harm to deployement .

Comment: Works for me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Right Click on project -> "Run as Maven Test". This will automatically download the missing plugin. & after that, Right Click on project ->"Update Maven project" it removes the error

Answer (score 2):

**@SpringBootApplication** annotation contains these configurations.

1) @Configuration

2) @ComponentScan

3) @EnableAutoConfiguration

**@EnableAutoConfiguration** is the reason for this error. This will try to automatically configure application according to dependencies in your pom.xml

As a example when you have spring-data-jpa dependency in pom it will try to add configuration to application by looking at application.properties file for data source. So you need add data source to solve that.

**mvn clean install -DskipTests** will help you to skip testing until you solve the error.

Answer (score 1):

If You are facing above problem while building your maven project. Then please try to put below code in you pom.xml file.

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Problem might be occurring because version of surefire plugin might be incorrect or not downloaded.

Comment: curiously enough, for me, changing version from 2.20.1 to the latest 3.0.0-M1 did solve the problem with surefire plugin reporting crashes which didn't seem to connect with obvious test failures

Answer (score 0):

You can add these tag in pom.xml

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>true</skipTests>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this is downvoted? A similiar answer is provided that's upvoted. Not very helpful to future readers. This works for me but want to make sure it's good design

Answer (score 0):

Also, this issue may occur if you changed the path to your tests. In that case, the tests cannot be found and therefore executed.