# Aerospike-loader installation giving error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python-3.x, maven-2, aerospike, aerospike-loader

when i am trying to install aerospike-loader using **mvn clean install** command, it gives error. Below is the result of **mvn clean install** command.At the end of result it shows error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Aerospike Loader
[INFO]    task-segment: [clean, install]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [clean:clean {execution: default-clean}]
[INFO] Deleting /home/ubuntu/Arti/Setup/aerospike-loader-master/target
[INFO] [resources:resources {execution: default-resources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] [compiler:compile {execution: default-compile}]
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to /home/ubuntu/Arti/Setup/aerospike-loader-master/target/classes
[INFO] [resources:testResources {execution: default-testResources}]
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 14 resources
[INFO] [compiler:testCompile {execution: default-testCompile}]
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /home/ubuntu/Arti/Setup/aerospike-loader-master/target/test-classes
[INFO] [surefire:test {execution: default-test}]
[INFO] Surefire report directory: /home/ubuntu/Arti/Setup/aerospike-loader-master/target/surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.aerospike.load.CsvFileParserTest
TestValidateTimestampInteger: start
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :99  - Aerospike loader started
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :199  - Number of data files:1
INFO  Parser           :165  - Number of columns: 2(metadata) + 1(bins)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :210  - Config file processed.
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :406  - Parameters:[ host=127.0.0.1, port=3000, ns=test, set=null, ttl=-1, timeout=0, write-action=UPDATE, fileType=csv, delimiter=,, timeZoneOffset=0, ignoreFirstLine=true, abortErrorCount=0]
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :415  - Reader pool size : 1
INFO  PrintStat        :85  - 2016-04-03 02:27:57 load(Write count=0 tps=0 Errors=0 (Timeout:0 KeyExists:0 othersWrites:0 ReadErrors:0 Processing:0) Progress:0%
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :425  - Shutdown down reader thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :541  - Processing: data.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :536  - Reader completed 11-lines in 0.054sec, From file: data.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :429  - Reader thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :433  - Shutdown down writer thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :436  - Writer thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :439  - Final Statistics of importer: (Succesfull Writes = 10, Errors=0(0-Write,0-Read,0-Processing)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :451  - Aerospike loader completed
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set1 key=key1 bin=dob value=8/20/80 generation=9 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set2 key=key2 bin=dob value=9/3/93 generation=9 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set3 key=key3 bin=dob value=6/0/90 generation=9 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set4 key=key4 bin=dob value=10/16/46 generation=9 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set0 key=key5 bin=dob value=8/26/56 generation=9 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set1 key=key6 bin=dob value=1/7/97 generation=9 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set2 key=key7 bin=dob value=4/28/88 generation=9 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set3 key=key8 bin=dob value=9/21/81 generation=9 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set4 key=key9 bin=dob value=2/14/14 generation=9 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set0 key=key10 bin=dob value=11/23/23 generation=9 expiration=0
TestValidateTimestampInteger: Complete
Test static BinName: start
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :99  - Aerospike loader started
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :199  - Number of data files:1
INFO  Parser           :165  - Number of columns: 2(metadata) + 1(bins)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :210  - Config file processed.
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :406  - Parameters:[ host=127.0.0.1, port=3000, ns=test, set=null, ttl=-1, timeout=0, write-action=UPDATE, fileType=csv, delimiter=,, timeZoneOffset=0, ignoreFirstLine=true, abortErrorCount=0]
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :415  - Reader pool size : 1
INFO  PrintStat        :85  - 2016-04-03 02:27:58 load(Write count=10 tps=10 Errors=0 (Timeout:0 KeyExists:0 othersWrites:0 ReadErrors:0 Processing:0) Progress:55%
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :541  - Processing: staticBinData.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :425  - Shutdown down reader thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :536  - Reader completed 4-lines in 0.026sec, From file: staticBinData.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :429  - Reader thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :433  - Shutdown down writer thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :436  - Writer thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :439  - Final Statistics of importer: (Succesfull Writes = 13, Errors=0(0-Write,0-Read,0-Processing)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :451  - Aerospike loader completed
Test static BinName: Complete
TestValidateString: start
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :99  - Aerospike loader started
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :199  - Number of data files:1
INFO  Parser           :165  - Number of columns: 2(metadata) + 1(bins)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :210  - Config file processed.
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :406  - Parameters:[ host=127.0.0.1, port=3000, ns=test, set=null, ttl=-1, timeout=0, write-action=UPDATE, fileType=csv, delimiter=,, timeZoneOffset=0, ignoreFirstLine=true, abortErrorCount=0]
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :415  - Reader pool size : 1
INFO  PrintStat        :85  - 2016-04-03 02:27:58 load(Write count=13 tps=13 Errors=0 (Timeout:0 KeyExists:0 othersWrites:0 ReadErrors:0 Processing:0) Progress:62%
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :541  - Processing: data.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :425  - Shutdown down reader thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :536  - Reader completed 11-lines in 0.051sec, From file: data.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :429  - Reader thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :433  - Shutdown down writer thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :436  - Writer thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :439  - Final Statistics of importer: (Succesfull Writes = 23, Errors=0(0-Write,0-Read,0-Processing)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :451  - Aerospike loader completed
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set1 key=key1 bin=loc value=loc80 generation=10 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set2 key=key2 bin=loc value=loc93 generation=10 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set3 key=key3 bin=loc value=loc90 generation=10 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set4 key=key4 bin=loc value=loc46 generation=10 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set0 key=key5 bin=loc value=loc56 generation=10 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set1 key=key6 bin=loc value=loc97 generation=10 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set2 key=key7 bin=loc value=loc88 generation=10 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set3 key=key8 bin=loc value=loc81 generation=10 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set4 key=key9 bin=loc value=loc14 generation=10 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set0 key=key10 bin=loc value=loc23 generation=10 expiration=0
TestValidateString: Complete
TestValidateStringUtf8: start
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :99  - Aerospike loader started
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :199  - Number of data files:1
INFO  Parser           :165  - Number of columns: 2(metadata) + 1(bins)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :210  - Config file processed.
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :406  - Parameters:[ host=127.0.0.1, port=3000, ns=test, set=null, ttl=-1, timeout=0, write-action=UPDATE, fileType=csv, delimiter=,, timeZoneOffset=0, ignoreFirstLine=true, abortErrorCount=0]
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :415  - Reader pool size : 1
INFO  PrintStat        :85  - 2016-04-03 02:27:58 load(Write count=23 tps=23 Errors=0 (Timeout:0 KeyExists:0 othersWrites:0 ReadErrors:0 Processing:0) Progress:69%
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :425  - Shutdown down reader thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :541  - Processing: data.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :536  - Reader completed 11-lines in 0.027sec, From file: data.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :429  - Reader thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :433  - Shutdown down writer thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :436  - Writer thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :439  - Final Statistics of importer: (Succesfull Writes = 33, Errors=0(0-Write,0-Read,0-Processing)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :451  - Aerospike loader completed
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set1 key=key1 bin=UTF8 value=Ûtf880 generation=11 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set2 key=key2 bin=UTF8 value=Ûtf893 generation=11 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set3 key=key3 bin=UTF8 value=Ûtf890 generation=11 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set4 key=key4 bin=UTF8 value=Ûtf846 generation=11 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set0 key=key5 bin=UTF8 value=Ûtf856 generation=11 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set1 key=key6 bin=UTF8 value=Ûtf897 generation=11 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set2 key=key7 bin=UTF8 value=Ûtf888 generation=11 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set3 key=key8 bin=UTF8 value=Ûtf881 generation=11 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set4 key=key9 bin=UTF8 value=Ûtf814 generation=11 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set0 key=key10 bin=UTF8 value=Ûtf823 generation=11 expiration=0
TestValidateStringutf8: Complete
Test Dynamic BinName: start
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :99  - Aerospike loader started
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :199  - Number of data files:1
INFO  Parser           :165  - Number of columns: 2(metadata) + 2(bins)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :210  - Config file processed.
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :406  - Parameters:[ host=127.0.0.1, port=3000, ns=test, set=null, ttl=-1, timeout=0, write-action=UPDATE, fileType=csv, delimiter=,, timeZoneOffset=0, ignoreFirstLine=true, abortErrorCount=0]
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :415  - Reader pool size : 1
INFO  PrintStat        :85  - 2016-04-03 02:27:58 load(Write count=33 tps=33 Errors=0 (Timeout:0 KeyExists:0 othersWrites:0 ReadErrors:0 Processing:0) Progress:68%
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :541  - Processing: dynamicBinData.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :425  - Shutdown down reader thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :536  - Reader completed 4-lines in 0.039sec, From file: dynamicBinData.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :429  - Reader thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :433  - Shutdown down writer thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :436  - Writer thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :439  - Final Statistics of importer: (Succesfull Writes = 36, Errors=0(0-Write,0-Read,0-Processing)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :451  - Aerospike loader completed
Test Dynamic BinName: Complete
TestAllDatatype: start
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :99  - Aerospike loader started
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :199  - Number of data files:1
INFO  Parser           :165  - Number of columns: 2(metadata) + 4(bins)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :210  - Config file processed.
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :406  - Parameters:[ host=127.0.0.1, port=3000, ns=test, set=null, ttl=-1, timeout=0, write-action=UPDATE, fileType=csv, delimiter=,, timeZoneOffset=0, ignoreFirstLine=true, abortErrorCount=0]
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :415  - Reader pool size : 1
INFO  PrintStat        :85  - 2016-04-03 02:27:59 load(Write count=36 tps=36 Errors=0 (Timeout:0 KeyExists:0 othersWrites:0 ReadErrors:0 Processing:0) Progress:16%
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :425  - Shutdown down reader thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :541  - Processing: data.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :536  - Reader completed 101-lines in 0.090sec, From file: data.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :429  - Reader thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :433  - Shutdown down writer thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :436  - Writer thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :439  - Final Statistics of importer: (Succesfull Writes = 136, Errors=0(0-Write,0-Read,0-Processing)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :451  - Aerospike loader completed
TestAllDatatype: Complete
TestValidateInteger: start
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :99  - Aerospike loader started
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :199  - Number of data files:1
INFO  Parser           :165  - Number of columns: 2(metadata) + 1(bins)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :210  - Config file processed.
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :406  - Parameters:[ host=127.0.0.1, port=3000, ns=test, set=null, ttl=-1, timeout=0, write-action=UPDATE, fileType=csv, delimiter=,, timeZoneOffset=0, ignoreFirstLine=true, abortErrorCount=0]
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :415  - Reader pool size : 1
INFO  PrintStat        :85  - 2016-04-03 02:27:59 load(Write count=136 tps=136 Errors=0 (Timeout:0 KeyExists:0 othersWrites:0 ReadErrors:0 Processing:0) Progress:97%
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :425  - Shutdown down reader thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :541  - Processing: data.csv
ERROR AsWriterTask     :228  - File:data.csv Line:2 Integer/Long Parse Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "key1"
ERROR AsWriterTask     :228  - File:data.csv Line:3 Integer/Long Parse Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "key2"
ERROR AsWriterTask     :228  - File:data.csv Line:8 Integer/Long Parse Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "key7"
ERROR AsWriterTask     :228  - File:data.csv Line:9 Integer/Long Parse Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "key8"
ERROR AsWriterTask     :228  - File:data.csv Line:4 Integer/Long Parse Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "key3"
ERROR AsWriterTask     :228  - File:data.csv Line:10 Integer/Long Parse Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "key9"
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :536  - Reader completed 11-lines in 0.041sec, From file: data.csv
ERROR AsWriterTask     :228  - File:data.csv Line:7 Integer/Long Parse Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "key6"
ERROR AsWriterTask     :228  - File:data.csv Line:11 Integer/Long Parse Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "key10"
ERROR AsWriterTask     :228  - File:data.csv Line:5 Integer/Long Parse Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "key4"
ERROR AsWriterTask     :228  - File:data.csv Line:6 Integer/Long Parse Error:java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "key5"
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :429  - Reader thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :433  - Shutdown down writer thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :436  - Writer thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :439  - Final Statistics of importer: (Succesfull Writes = 136, Errors=0(0-Write,0-Read,0-Processing)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :451  - Aerospike loader completed
Put/Get mismatch: Expected 80. Received null.
Put/Get mismatch: Expected 93. Received null.
Put/Get mismatch: Expected 90. Received null.
Put/Get mismatch: Expected 46. Received null.
Put/Get mismatch: Expected 56. Received null.
Put/Get mismatch: Expected 97. Received null.
Put/Get mismatch: Expected 88. Received null.
Put/Get mismatch: Expected 81. Received null.
Put/Get mismatch: Expected 14. Received null.
Put/Get mismatch: Expected 23. Received null.
TestValidateBlob: start
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :99  - Aerospike loader started
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :199  - Number of data files:1
INFO  Parser           :165  - Number of columns: 2(metadata) + 1(bins)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :210  - Config file processed.
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :406  - Parameters:[ host=127.0.0.1, port=3000, ns=test, set=null, ttl=-1, timeout=0, write-action=UPDATE, fileType=csv, delimiter=,, timeZoneOffset=0, ignoreFirstLine=true, abortErrorCount=0]
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :415  - Reader pool size : 1
INFO  PrintStat        :85  - 2016-04-03 02:28:00 load(Write count=136 tps=136 Errors=0 (Timeout:0 KeyExists:0 othersWrites:0 ReadErrors:0 Processing:0) Progress:93%
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :425  - Shutdown down reader thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :541  - Processing: data.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :536  - Reader completed 11-lines in 0.045sec, From file: data.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :429  - Reader thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :433  - Shutdown down writer thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :436  - Writer thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :439  - Final Statistics of importer: (Succesfull Writes = 146, Errors=0(0-Write,0-Read,0-Processing)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :451  - Aerospike loader completed
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set1 key=key1 bin=loc value=loc80 generation=12 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set2 key=key2 bin=loc value=loc93 generation=12 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set3 key=key3 bin=loc value=loc90 generation=12 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set4 key=key4 bin=loc value=loc46 generation=12 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set0 key=key5 bin=loc value=loc56 generation=12 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set1 key=key6 bin=loc value=loc97 generation=12 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set2 key=key7 bin=loc value=loc88 generation=12 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set3 key=key8 bin=loc value=loc81 generation=12 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set4 key=key9 bin=loc value=loc14 generation=12 expiration=0
Bin matched: namespace=test set=set0 key=key10 bin=loc value=loc23 generation=12 expiration=0
TestValidateList: start
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :99  - Aerospike loader started
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :199  - Number of data files:1
INFO  Parser           :165  - Number of columns: 2(metadata) + 3(bins)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :210  - Config file processed.
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :406  - Parameters:[ host=127.0.0.1, port=3000, ns=test, set=null, ttl=-1, timeout=0, write-action=UPDATE, fileType=csv, delimiter=,, timeZoneOffset=0, ignoreFirstLine=true, abortErrorCount=0]
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :415  - Reader pool size : 1
INFO  PrintStat        :85  - 2016-04-03 02:28:00 load(Write count=146 tps=146 Errors=0 (Timeout:0 KeyExists:0 othersWrites:0 ReadErrors:0 Processing:0) Progress:93%
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :425  - Shutdown down reader thread pool
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :541  - Processing: list-data.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :536  - Reader completed 5-lines in 0.032sec, From file: list-data.csv
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :429  - Reader thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :433  - Shutdown down writer thread pool
ERROR AsWriterTask     :381  - File:list-data.csv Line:3 Aerospike Bin processing Error:Error Code 1500: /opt/aerospike/sys/udf/lua/ldt/lib_llist.lua:5639 LDT-Not Enabled on Namespace ResultCode: 1500
ERROR AsWriterTask     :381  - File:list-data.csv Line:5 Aerospike Bin processing Error:Error Code 1500: /opt/aerospike/sys/udf/lua/ldt/lib_llist.lua:5639 LDT-Not Enabled on Namespace ResultCode: 1500
ERROR AsWriterTask     :381  - File:list-data.csv Line:2 Aerospike Bin processing Error:Error Code 1500: /opt/aerospike/sys/udf/lua/ldt/lib_llist.lua:5639 LDT-Not Enabled on Namespace ResultCode: 1500
ERROR AsWriterTask     :381  - File:list-data.csv Line:4 Aerospike Bin processing Error:Error Code 1500: /opt/aerospike/sys/udf/lua/ldt/lib_llist.lua:5639 LDT-Not Enabled on Namespace ResultCode: 1500
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :436  - Writer thread pool terminated
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :439  - Final Statistics of importer: (Succesfull Writes = 146, Errors=4(0-Write,0-Read,4-Processing)
INFO  AerospikeLoad    :451  - Aerospike loader completed
Tests run: 9, Failures: 2, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.726 sec <<< FAILURE! - in com.aerospike.load.CsvFileParserTest
testValidateInteger(com.aerospike.load.CsvFileParserTest)  Time elapsed: 0.418 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
    at com.aerospike.load.CsvFileParserTest.testValidateInteger(CsvFileParserTest.java:141)

testValidateBlob(com.aerospike.load.CsvFileParserTest)  Time elapsed: 0.341 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: null
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:86)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:52)
    at com.aerospike.load.CsvFileParserTest.testValidateBlob(CsvFileParserTest.java:234)

testValidateList(com.aerospike.load.CsvFileParserTest)  Time elapsed: 0.38 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.aerospike.load.CsvFileParserTest.testValidateList(CsvFileParserTest.java:259)


Results :

Failed tests: 
  CsvFileParserTest.testValidateInteger:141 null
  CsvFileParserTest.testValidateBlob:234 null

Tests in error: 
  CsvFileParserTest.testValidateList:259 NullPointer

Tests run: 9, Failures: 2, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] There are test failures.

Please refer to /home/ubuntu/Arti/Setup/aerospike-loader-master/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] For more information, run Maven with the -e switch
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 20 seconds
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Apr 03 02:28:01 IST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 32M/76M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Are you trying to upload some LDTs from the csv file? Looks like you may need to sanitize some of the data in :list-data.csv.  ERROR AsWriterTask     :381  - File:list-data.csv Line:4 Aerospike Bin processing Error:Error Code 1500: /opt/aerospike/sys/udf/lua/ldt/lib_llist.lua:5639 LDT-Not Enabled on Namespace ResultCode: 1500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had follow below link

**[Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221182/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-18-1tes)**

and run command again with **mvn clean install -DskipTests**

Answer (score 1):

First of all these are unit testcases along with the package. You may not face issues when you load your data. Please proceed and let us know if you face any issue with your data load.

One of the main failure is because ldt is not enabled in your namespace. You can ignore this if you are not using ldt. There is one more error with integers. We will look into that failure.