# AWS lambda Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, aws-lambda, aws-serverless

I'm deploying a AWS lambda function using java as primary language , here below I share my java class code and my maven pom.xml file:

```
package com.amazonaws.lambda.demo;

import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.Context;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.RequestHandler;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.KinesisEvent;
import com.amazonaws.services.lambda.runtime.events.KinesisEvent.KinesisEventRecord;

public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<KinesisEvent, Integer> {

    @Override
    public Integer handleRequest(KinesisEvent event, Context context) {
        context.getLogger().log("Input: " + event);

        for (KinesisEventRecord rec : event.getRecords()) {
            System.out.println(new String(rec.getKinesis().getData().array()));
        }
        return null;   
    }
}
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.amazonaws.lambda</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
          <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M1</version>
    </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.529</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.12</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-events</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.528</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I run a local test I get the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M1:test
>   (default-test) on project demo: There are test failures. [ERROR] 
>   [ERROR] Please refer to
>   /home/andrw/eclipse-workspace/kinesis-consumer/target/surefire-reports
>   for the individual test results. [ERROR] Please refer to dump files
>   (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and
>   [date].dumpstream. [ERROR] -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the
>   full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible
>   solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Comment: People who ask about test failures usually post a test source code

Comment: Seems issue with surefire version. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221182/failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-plugin2-18-1tes?rq=1